# event filtering in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, filter

Here I have a `data` as follows:

```
data<-data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
                 event=c(1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0))
```

I want to remake `data` by the following rules. `id` means a personal number. For each `id` if `id` has at least one event, then only filer the rows with events. However, if 'id' ahs no event, then do not filter the rows.

In this case,`id`=1 and 2 has events but, `id`=3 has no events. So the expected output of `data` should be like this:

```
data<-data.frame(id=c(1,1,2,3,3,3),
                 event=c(1,1,1,0,0,0))
```

Comment: How about `data %>% group_by(id) %>% filter(event == max(event))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filtering criteria is `event == 1` OR the maximum value of `event` for that `id` is `0`. So:

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
        group_by(id) %>%
        filter(event==1 | max(event)==0)
```